# How to create a multidimensional array from lists with NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

There should be a way to turn a lists like this:

```
a = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
b = [[6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```

to something like this:

```
c = [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

Right now I'm accomplishing this using `for` loops.

```
c = []
for pos in range(len(a)):
    c.append([a[pos], b[pos]])
```

Anyway `for` loops are slow and, not to sound like an infomercial but, there has got to be a better way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use [`column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> np.column_stack((a, b))
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

`column_stack` coerces the lists to arrays first and returns an array.

Since `a` and `b` are both a list of lists of a single element, each becomes a 2D column vector when coerced to an array. Because of this fact, you could also use [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) or [`concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to achieve the same thing (they also coerce the lists to arrays that have the correct shape for what we want). Use `np.hstack((a, b))` or `np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)`.

For completeness, it's also possible to use [`np.c_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) by writing `np.c_[a, b]`. The other methods are more direct and possibly faster though.

Answer (score 2):

A non-numpy solution is

```
In [10]: zip(a,b)
Out[10]: [([1], [6]), ([2], [7]), ([3], [8]), ([4], [9]), ([5], [10])]
```

Oops - not quite.  Without the inner brackets, `zip` does a nice job of regrouping lists:

```
In [11]: zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
Out[11]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Playing around a bit more, I get

```
In [12]: zip(zip(*a)[0],zip(*b)[0])
Out[12]: [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

I'm also a big fan of list comprehensions. They are a form of looping, but compact and about as fast as possible with plain Python.  Here too I need `[0]` to pull terms out of the inner lists.

```
In [25]: [[i[0],j[0]] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
Out[25]: [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

`itertools.chain` is another good tool for flattening nested lists:

```
In [31]: zip(*(itertools.chain(*a),itertools.chain(*b)))
Out[31]: [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

But since you mention `numpy` we can use:

```
In [18]: np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1)
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

The basic `concatenate` works because `np.array(a)` produces a `(5,1)` array.  So 2 such arrays can be joined into a `(5,2)` array without any further shape adjustment.

To get back to the nested list format, use `tolist` on that array.

```
In [19]: np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1).tolist()
Out[19]: [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

`hstack` and `column_stack` also join on the `1` axis, adjusting dimensions if needed.  But I like the explicit control that `np.concatenate` gives (and requires).